# What does ::marker in html of inspector window mean?

Tags: html, css, web-inspector

I saw in debug console there is an element like following
[image]

```
<li>
    ::marker
    Wait until your DNS configuration changes. This could take up to 72 hours.
</li>
```

What does this `::marker` mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The `::marker` CSS pseudo-element selects the marker box of a list item,
> which typically contains a bullet or number. It works on any element
> or pseudo-element set to `display: list-item`, such as the `<li>` and
> `<summary>` elements.

— https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::marker